# If I divide 3 by 2 I want the answer to be 2 (ie 1.5 rounded to 2)

Tags: c, decimal, rounding

How to get he upper limit of a number in C?

If I divide 3 by 2 I want the answer to be 2 (ie 1.5 rounded to 2).

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of SO 2422712 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422712/c-rounding-number-up).  Granted that question mentions floating point, but the answers so far here do too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ceil(number)](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/ceil.html)

Answer (score 12):

If you are just interested in dividing by 2, then just take (n + 1) / 2 to keep it in integer math. For example (3 + 1) / 2 gives 2. For a larger number x, use x - 1. For example, (3 + 7) / 8 = 1, for 3 divided by 8.

For the general case, you are looking for the ceiling function -- ceil. A quick Google search for "math ceil C" gave this page at the top of the results: http://www.elook.org/programming/c/ceil.html

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <math.h>
ceil(3.0/2); //2.0
```

Note that one the operands should be double(or float) because 3/2 gives you 1

Comment: Are you sure `2/3.0` == `2.0`?

Answer (score 2):

```
int x= ceil((float)3/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

To round without using functions, just add half of the divisor before you divide.
if the divisor is a constant, the compiler with optimize the code nicely.

```
int  number = 3;
int  divisor = 2;
int  result = (number + (divisor+1)/2) / divisor;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 3;
int j = 2;
int k = (i + j - 1) / j;
```

Answer (score 1):

(If this qualifies as thread necromancy, kindly notify and I'll delete this)

A quick way to return an upward-rounded quotient is to add the divisor, minus one, to the dividend, and divide.

```
int ceil_div(int dividend, int divisor) {
    return (dividend + divisor - 1) / divisor;
}
```

or alternatively,

```
int ceil_div(int dividend, int divisor) {
    return (dividend - 1) / divisor + 1;
}
```

Consequentially, you'll work by subtracting 1 from 3, dividing by 2, and adding 1.

I'll try and explain why this works. If *dividend* and *divisor* were both floats, then the truncated integer equivalent of (*dividend*/*divisor*) would be equal to the ceiling of the quotient if *divisor perfectly divides dividend*, or one less if it *does not perfectly divide dividend*. By subtracting 1, we guarantee that the new dividend, *dividend - 1*, when divided by *divisor*, will always return a value lesser than the ceiling of the floating point quotient.

All that remains now is adding 1 to this quotient, which, incidentally, is floor((float) dividend / (float) divisor).

Comment: An easier approach when dealing with positive numbers *in languages which implement integer division using floored or Euclidian arithmetic* is to negate the dividend and the result (i.e. x/y rounding up is -((-x) // y).  Unfortunately, many languages implement the rather less useful truncate-toward-zero integer division, and this technique won't work with those.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 3.0/2 + 0.5;
```

Comment: OP is asking for the ceiling function, not the round function. I too thought of this until I realized he *always* wants the next greatest integer regardless of th evalue.

Comment: Ah. That wasn't entirely clear for me. He does use the word "rounded to.." :s