# What is the right way to round dividing to integers?

Tags: c#, math

I am dividing 2 integers and looking to get an integer as a result.  I want the right `Math.Round()` method so when I divide, it always round to the next integer regardless of how.  Here are a bunch of examples with expectations below.

```
int result = (6/4); // = 2
int result = (3/4);  // = 1
int result = (1/4);  // = 1
int result = (8/4);  // = 2
int result = (9/4);  // = 3
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Question: Do you care about negative values? For example, using `Math.Ceiling` on `-9d/4d` will give you `-2` and not `-3`.

Comment: [Rounding integer division (instead of truncating)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2422712/995714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since all the integers in your example are positive, I'll assume that you are not interested in the case where one or both operands are negative or zero.

`Math.Round` works on floating-point numbers. That is not necessary here.

Dividing two integers gives an integer result. It always rounds down. You want something like this:

```
int Divide(int numerator, int denominator) {
    return (numerator + denominator - 1) / denominator;
}
```

For example,for `1/4`, we get `(1 + 4 - 1) / 4 = 4 / 4 = 1`, and for `8/4` we get `(8 + 4 - 1) / 4 = 11 / 4 = 2`.

There's a very slight possibility of overflow here, so if the numerator is always greater than zero, it's better to use:

```
int Divide(int numerator, int denominator) {
    return 1 + (numerator - 1) / denominator;
}
```

Comment: leora hasn't specified, but this can produce incorrect results for negative integers: `Divide(-9,  4)` results in `-1` (which I believe is incorrect) (also, I think you may have mixed up `denominator` and `numerator`)

Comment: It seems to work. But the names `denominator` and `numerator` ought to be swapped, I believe.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks to both of you for pointing it out. I am remarkably good at making that mistake. In my native language, the word for denominator sounds like "numer."

Comment: This is superior to converting to `float` because it will work in cases where `float` can underflow and through the loss of precision return the wrong answer. I use this technique regularly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to perform division as float/double and use [Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx):

> Math.Ceiling... Returns the smallest integral value that is greater than or equal to the specified double-precision floating-point number.

Sample:

```
 int result = (int)Math.Ceiling(6/4.0);
 result = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)3/4);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not the method you are looking for...

```
int mod = 9 % 4;
int result = (9 - mod) / 4) + (mod > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Does not require any casting or usage of the Math class.

Comment: Jeffrey Sax's method achieves the same effect and to me is more natural.

Comment: True, but his method uses internal casting, as well as requires a check to make sure the numerator is not zero. I'm really splitting hairs here...

Comment: Why do you have to check whether the numerator is zero? If the division is `0 / 5` for example, you get 0 through `(0 + 4) / 5`. And what internal casting? You're using `int` just the same...

Comment: My method doesn't have to check, Jeffrey Sax's method does. I'm not sure how to respond about the casting...I interpret cases such as "int Divide() { return .875; } as casting.

Comment: Brad, I think maybe you're confusing the methods... there's no floating point math in [Jeffrey Sax's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15100770/57611).

Answer (score 1):

The question is posed in a confusing manner, it asks for a ceil while talking about round. For the record, here is an integer round function for positive integers

```
private static int RoundDivide(int numerator, int denominator) {
    return (numerator + (denominator / 2)) / denominator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of those integers should be a `double`:

```
double result = (6d/4); // 1.5  
int rounded = (int)Math.Round(result, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: But these won't get the results desired. leora wants to ceiling the values. 9/4 = 2.25, rounded results in 2. The `MidpointRounding` only affects half-way values like `1.5`.

Comment: You're right. I've seen this too late. Answered by Alexei already.