# How to round a non-floating point number?

Tags: c, math, numbers, integer

How do I round a non-floating point number? e.g.  9107609 down to 91 or to 911, etc.

Comment: `9107609/100000` or `9107609/10000`

Answer (score 5):

Divide by 100000 or 10000, respectively. C division rounds towards zero, so the numbers will always be rounded down. To round to the nearest integer, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422712/c-rounding-integer-division-instead-of-truncating).

Comment: Is "rounding down" equivalent to truncating the decimal? E.g. 1.9 gets "rounded down" to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Something like `floor(number/(10^numberofdigitstocut))` or `ceil(number/(10^numberofdigitstocut))` would do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <math.h>

//returns n rounded to digits length
int round_int (int n, int digits)
{
   int d = floor (log10 (abs (n))) + 1; //number of digits in n

   return floor(n / pow(10, d-digits));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To *round*, use a half way addition (if positive, else subtract 10000/2)

```
int rounded = (9107609 + 10000/2)/10000;
```