# Is there any difference between the two ways to round a number to a multiple of 8 in C

Tags: c

If size is a int variable

```
int size = 10;
```

And I want to round up size to a multiple of 8, what is the difference between the two ways:

A:

```
size = 1 + ((size - 1)/8);
size = size * 8;
```

B:

```
size = (size/8+1)*8;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The one I've seen the most is `8 * ((size+7) / 8)`?

Comment: Are both working? Then semantically there is no difference. What is more efficient and readable? You can guess.

Comment: Wow.  Three answers saying essentially the same thing within 14s of each other.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's a strong evidence they are correct :)

Comment: Note that method A gives an incorrect result if `size` is zero.

Comment: At the very least, you should review [Rounding integer division instead of truncating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422712/).  I'd like to be convinced this isn't just a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any difference between [these] two ways to round a number to a multiple of 8 in C[?]

Yes.  They produce different results for inputs that are already multiples of 8.  Approach (A) returns such inputs unchanged, but approach (B) returns the next larger multiple of 8 (supposing no overflow).

Answer (score 2):

The two are doing different things:

- The first sequence correctly keeps multiples of 8 in place
- The second sequence rounds 8 up to 16, 16 up to 24, and so on.

Here is the sequence of outputs for both snippets for values 0..19, with differences highlighted:

- 0 8 8
- 1 8 8
- 2 8 8
- 3 8 8
- 4 8 8
- 5 8 8
- 6 8 8
- 7 8 8
- **8 8 16**
- 9 16 16
- 10 16 16
- 11 16 16
- 12 16 16
- 13 16 16
- 14 16 16
- 15 16 16
- **16 16 24**
- 17 24 24
- 18 24 24
- 19 24 24

Answer (score 2):

Method A keeps multiples of 8 the same value and rounds other values up.

Method B won't work for multiples of 8, as it rounds those up as well.

For example: `(16/8+1)*8 == (2+1)*8 == 3*8 == 24`.

Answer (score 1):

As others has stated, the A and B behave differently. Just try with `size = 8` for both. Solution B is for sure wrong as `8` results in `16`.

Rounding can be done in several ways. Especially negative numbers can be tricky. Should `-4` result in `-8` or `0`?

I would go for `round to nearste` with `Round half away from zero` like this:

```
size = (size >= 0) ? 8*((size+4)/8) : 8*((size-4)/8);
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding for more about rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Rounding up to a power of 2 can be done like

```
size = (size + 7) & (~7)
```

Sometimes helps when you're on a CPU that has no fast multiplication / division

Comment: 7 isn't a power of two.  You should explain a bit better (maybe if N is a power of two, then `(size + N - 1) & ~(N - 1)`…).

Answer (score 1):

Different results when `size` is `8, 16, 24, 32 ...`
Different results when `size` is `-7, -15, -23 ...`.

`A` is correct for values greater than 1.
`B` is not correct for positive multiples of 8.

Both fail for `size == 0`.  Unclear if `size < 0` is important for OP.

To do `unsigned` rounding up to a multiple of `N` which also works for `size == 0`.

```
#define N 8
unsigned size;
unsigned rounded_size = (size + N - 1) % N;
```