# Is there a more compact way of calculating the number of transactions required?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I need to calculate how many transactions are required to transmit n bytes. I can only read b bytes from the external hardware in a single transaction. The number of transactions is N. This pseudo-code seems sufficient:

```
If n=0 then
  N=0 // 0 transactions needed as no data has to be transferred IN or OUT
else
  if n%b then
    N=n/b+1 // n is not wholly divisible by b, thus the (last) Nth transaction shall transfer less than b bytes
  else
    N=n/b // all N transactions shall transfer exactly b bytes
  end if
end if
```

My question is simply, is there a more compact way to do this? I am checking using modulus operator that n%b is nonzero since if I have to transfer 3 bytes and the buffer is 8 bytes, then 3/8 shall be 0 in int but the +1 shall take care of it giving 1 transaction.

Comment: `N = (n + b - 1) / b;` maybe?

Comment: See [C rounding integer division (instead of truncating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422712/)

Comment: See Jonathan Leffler's rounding up answer in the linked question.

Comment: Aha... hmmmm... I ams dealing with an embedded system design here. No floating point unit. Truncation is ok. That is why I was adding 1.

Comment: All numbers are unsigned