# Why static definition of variable in C fails while compiling?

Tags: arrays, c, c-preprocessor, declaration, constant-expression

please could anyone help me why such a definition of symbolic constants yields error definition of following static variables within functions:
error: storage size of ‘variable’ isn’t constant

```
        #define SAMPLE_RATE 200 /* Sample rate in Hz. */
        #define MS_PER_SAMPLE   ( (double) 1000/ (double) SAMPLE_RATE)
        #define MS10    ((int) (10/ MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS25    ((int) (25/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS30    ((int) (30/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS80    ((int) (80/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS95    ((int) (95/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS100   ((int) (100/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS125   ((int) (125/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS150   ((int) (150/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS160   ((int) (160/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS175   ((int) (175/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS195   ((int) (195/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS200   ((int) (200/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS220   ((int) (220/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS250   ((int) (250/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS300   ((int) (300/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS360   ((int) (360/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS450   ((int) (450/MS_PER_SAMPLE + 0.5))
        #define MS1000  SAMPLE_RATE
        #define MS1500  ((int) (1500/MS_PER_SAMPLE))
        #define DERIV_LENGTH    MS10
        #define LPBUFFER_LGTH ((int) (2*MS25))
        #define HPBUFFER_LGTH MS125#define WINDOW_WIDTH MS80            // Moving window integration width.
    #define FILTER_DELAY (int) (((double) DERIV_LENGTH/2) + ((double) LPBUFFER_LGTH/2 - 1) + (((double) HPBUFFER_LGTH-1)/2) + PRE_BLANK)  // filter delays plus 200 ms blanking delay
    #define DER_DELAY   WINDOW_WIDTH + FILTER_DELAY + MS100



    int lpfilt( int datum ,int init)
        {
        static long y1 = 0, y2 = 0 ;
        static int data[MS_PER_SAMPLE], ptr = 0 ;
        .....

int lpfilt( int datum ,int init)
    {
    static int data[MS_PER_SAMPLE], ptr = 0 ;
....
int hpfilt( int datum, int init )
    {
    static int data[HPBUFFER_LGTH], ptr = 0 ;
...


int deriv1(int x, int init)
    {
    static int derBuff[DERIV_LENGTH], derI = 0 ;
...

int deriv2(int x, int init)
    {
    static int derBuff[DERIV_LENGTH], derI = 0 ;
...
int mvwint(int datum, int init)
    {
    static int data[WINDOW_WIDTH], ptr = 0 ;
...
```

I haven't a clue what the problem might be, no matter if I retype the result of calculation with (int) it still yields an error. Is retyping not allowed in symbolic constant definition?

Comment: You may not use a double values as the size of an array.

Comment: Please edit your code into a proper [mre]. One *complete* function (closing brace and no "...") and one or two macros should be enough to reproduce the error (which you should copy verbatim). Dumping poorly formatted, redacted and grossly ill-formed code on us to sift through isn't helping us to help you.

Comment: To compile it your compiler has to have this as an extension, clang compilers it without any problems, gcc fails (is more conforming) https://godbolt.org/z/8nezP6

Answer (score 0):

The expression used in this manifest constant

```
#define MS_PER_SAMPLE   ( (double) 1000/ (double) SAMPLE_RATE)
```

has the type double.

It is not an integer constant expression.

So you may not use this manifest constant as a size of an array as for example in this declaration.

```
static int data[MS_PER_SAMPLE], ptr = 0 ;
```

You could define the constant as for example

```
#define MS_PER_SAMPLE   ( ( int ) ( 1000.0 / SAMPLE_RATE ) )
```

Or keeping the manifest constant declaration as is you could write

```
static int data[( int )MS_PER_SAMPLE], ptr = 0 ;
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this: #define MS_PER_SAMPLE   ( ( int ) ( 1000.0 / SAMPLE_RATE ) )
and the error for first variable is gone, but appears for this: qrsfilt.c:125:13: error: storage size of ‘data’ isn’t constant
  static int data[HPBUFFER_LGTH], ptr = 0 ;

Comment: @IvoHora Without seeing the result code I can say nothing.  Relative to the error message the reason is the same or the value of the array size if equal to 0. Close the question and ask a new providing  a corresponding code.

Comment: Thank you, I put it to the answer, hope it is also fine

Answer (score 0):

> Why static definition of variable in C fails while compiling?

You cannot use `+ 0.5` in your constants. Research how to round an integer using only integers.

The array size has to be a constant expression. From [cppreference constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression):

> An integer constant expression is an expression that consists only of
>
> - [... other points ....]
> - floating constants, but only if they are immediately used as operands of casts to integer type

The `double` value `0.5` is not "immediately casts" (like `(int)0.5`), but is used with operator `+` to add an `int` with it. Thus the error.

Looking at your code, the proof of concept could look like this:

```
// the simplest based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422712/rounding-integer-division-instead-of-truncating
// but see also https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L132
#define DIV_ROUND(x, d)  ((x + (d / 2)) / d)

#define SAMPLE_RATE 200 /* Sample rate in Hz. */
#define MS_PER_SAMPLE   (1000 / SAMPLE_RATE)
#define MS125   DIV_ROUND(125, MS_PER_SAMPLE)
#define HPBUFFER_LGTH MS125
static int data[HPBUFFER_LGTH];
```

Because I see `(int)` spawned everywhere in your code, it would be a great time to read about [types of integer constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant), about [conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion). Because you work with macros, be sure to understand [macro pitfalls](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html).

Answer (score 0):

KamilCuk was right, constant 0.5 is not valid in my symbolic constant. Changing 0.5 to 1/2 and also removing all casting to (double) solved the issue. Thank you very much.