# What is the point of the logical operators in C?

Tags: c, xor, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I was just wondering if there is an XOR logical operator in C (something like && for AND but for XOR). I know I can split an XOR into ANDs, NOTs and ORs but a simple XOR would be much better. Then it occurred to me that if I use the normal XOR bitwise operator between two conditions, it might just work. And for my tests it did.

Consider:

```
int i = 3;
int j = 7;
int k = 8;
```

Just for the sake of this rather stupid example, if I need *k* to be either greater than *i* or greater than *j* but not both, XOR would be quite handy.

```
if ((k > i) XOR (k > j))
   printf("Valid");
else
   printf("Invalid");
```

or

```
printf("%s",((k > i) XOR (k > j)) ? "Valid" : "Invalid");
```

I put the bitwise XOR *^* and it produced "Invalid". Putting the results of the two comparisons in two integers resulted in the 2 integers to contain a 1, hence the XOR produced a false. I've then tried it with the & and | bitwise operators and both gave the expected results. All this makes sense knowing that true conditions have a non zero value, whilst false conditions have zero values.

I was wondering, is there a reason to use the logical && and || when the bitwise operators &, | and ^ work just the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical XOR operator in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596668/logical-xor-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need logical XOR, I have forgotten the SO question, but it's similar to what you're thinking, basically we don't need XOR, it's equivalent to **!=** anyway

```
FALSE XOR FALSE == FALSE
FALSE XOR TRUE == TRUE
TRUE XOR FALSE == TRUE
TRUE XOR TRUE == FALSE


FALSE != FALSE == FALSE
FALSE != TRUE == TRUE
TRUE != FALSE == TRUE
TRUE != TRUE == FALSE
```

I'll search my favorites, and paste here the link later...

Comment: `&`, `|`, and `^` might work the same as `||` and `&&` when used on *boolean* values, but normally you don't use `&`, `|`, and `^` on booleans -- you use them to work with bits (hence why they're *bitwise* operators). When used appropriately, the bitwise operators aren't the same as the logical operators.

Comment: historically, bitwise operators and logical operators share a common token (i.e. `&` and `|`), there's no `&&` and `||` yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930042/equivalent-of-visual-basics-and-and-or-in-c/3930123#3930123 Check the Neonatal C: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html  And it is unfortunate that they retain the old operator precedence of `&` and `|` when they added `&&` and `||` to C. hence this unfortunate parenthesisation(sic) on masking idiom: `if ( (input & alt) == alt )`. Otherwise, it could be more concise: `if ( input & alt == alt )`

Comment: That's not true. != isn't a logical xor. See: `2 LOGICAL_XOR 4` gives `false` (which is true), but `2 != 4` yields `true` (which is incorrect). The right answer is below ([Joe D answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773186/what-is-the-point-of-the-logical-operators-in-c/2938554#2938554) )

Comment: Since the asker asked about logical operator, both numbers needed be properly reduced to booleans first before applying whatever operator/macro to both booleans.  Just apply double nots on each side of the expression. !!2 != !!4 yields false.  i.e. true != true yields false

Comment: !! is the most idiomatic way to reduce the number to a boolean. If there's any other technique, I would be more than glad to know :-)

Answer (score 11):

The bitwise operators do not work "just the same" as the && and || operator. For a start, && and || perform short-circuited evaluation, whereas the the bitwise operators do not. In other words, you can't do something like this with the bitwise operators:

```
int * p = 0;
(p != 0) && (*p = 1);
```

because if you said:

```
(p != 0) & (*p = 1);
```

both subexpressions would be evaluated, and you would dereference the null pointer.

Comment: Internally no, but I still got the same results

Comment: @reubensammut: You will not get the same results if you depend on the short-circuitedness. `if(returnsTrue() || explodesWorld())` will not destroy the world, whereas `if(returnsTrue() | explodesWorld())` will.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise XOR does not work as would a logical XOR when its operands are integer values:

```
2^4 ? "Valid" : "Invalid"
```

gives "Valid" but should give "Invalid"

Comment: I meant XOR when used for conditions

Comment: In C, 2 is a valid way for expressing TRUE. Many people use it for checking a NULL pointer: `if (!p) ...`

Answer (score 1):

In C arguments of logical operators are treated as Boolean values - anything zero is treated as "false", and anything else (yes, negative values too) are "true". Bitwise ops work on individual bits, and as Neil already noted, are *not* subject to short-circuit evaluation as logical ops are.

In your example the results are totally valid and expected since bit-wise `xor` between two ones is zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a logical xor operator in C, then you can use this:

```
#define xor != 0 ^ !!
```

It works by converting both sides of the expression to booleans and xoring them.
You can use it as if you were using && or ||, like this:

```
if (a xor b)
```

AFAICT, there aren't any problems with it.