# Not short circuit operator

Tags: java

I understand this part:

```
    Integer myInt;
    myInt = new Integer(42);
    if (myInt != null && myInt.intValue() == 42) {
        System.out.println("Comparing 42 to 42");
    }
    myInt = null;
    if (myInt != null & myInt.intValue() == 42) {
        System.out.println("Comparing null to 42");
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Comparing 42 to 42
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What I dont understand is this:

```
System.out.println("Result:" +(1 & 3));
System.out.println("Result2:" +(2 | 3));
Result:1
Result2:3
```

If is not comparing booleans why give this results?

Comment: Bitwise and **and** bitwise or.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597978/are-the-bitwise-operators-or-logical-operators

Comment: @dnault, clearly dont respond to my question

Comment: I feel like @dnault linked to an excellent dupe which does explain the behavior you're seeing fairly concisely.

Comment: @dnault, no problem. I understand now. Read this article https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators

Comment: @Makoto, nowadays, seems that mark as duplicate is easier that respond to question. It was great If I saw an answer saying bitwise and then a calculation.

Comment: It'd be great if you assumed that no one meant you any offense in closing the question as a duplicate, and you followed the duplicate link to answers which would actually answer your question.

Comment: If the link is not explicity assuming any answer why I even assumed that? The link has a question which answer is on oracle docs.

Comment: "If is not comparing booleans why give this results?" My question was very clear. "Your question seemed focused on why..."  that´s an opinion.  If my question is unclear I can edit. Marked as duplicate is a lazy answer and must be discouranged