# What is XOR operator?

Tags: operator-keyword, xor

i know that xor operator returns true if both its input differ but with this knowledge i cant understand various coding problem across the internet.
like these:

https://www.hackerearth.com/february-easy-16/algorithm/utkarsh-and-sub-array-xor-february-easy/

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hourrank-5/challenges/xor-se

pls help me understand these.
btw i use c++ for coding. explaining how to use XOR operator in these will be enough, no need to explain the full question.

Comment: Google is your friend!

Comment: i tried with no luck. every result explains that " XOR operator returns true if both its input differ"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical xor operator in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596668/logical-xor-operator-in-c)

Comment: If you want a bitwise exclusive or, that's `operator ^`. If you want a boolean exclusive or, that's `operator !=`.

Answer (score 3):

An addition modulo 2 is equivalent to XOR.

```
0 XOR 0 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
```

equals to

```
( 0 + 0 ) mod 2 = 0
( 0 + 1 ) mod 2 = 1
( 1 + 0 ) mod 2 = 1
( 1 + 1 ) mod 2 = 0
```

Now you could use mod to solve XOR stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is no logical opertor xor in C/C++ and many other languages, only bitwise. It works separately for each corresponding bits of operands in there binary form.

Comment: There is a logical xor operator.  It is `!=`